# On reordering infinite product

Tags: proof-explanation, gamma-function, infinite-product, beta-function

In expressing $B(x,y)$ as an infinite product using the infinite product definition of $\Gamma(x)$, the book Special Functions by Andrews, et al doing this way : $$B(x,y)= \dfrac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)} = \dfrac{(x+y)e^{\gamma (x+y)} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{x+y}{n})e^{-\frac{x+y}{n}}}{xe^{\gamma x} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})e^{-\frac{x}{n}}ye^{\gamma y} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{y}{n})e^{-\frac{y}{n}}} = \dfrac{(x+y)}{xy} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(1+\frac{x+y}{n})}{(1+\frac{x}{n})(1+\frac{y}{n})}.$$ The last inequality is true if the following is true : $$\dfrac{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{x+y}{n})e^{-\frac{x+y}{n}}}{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})e^{-\frac{x}{n}}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{y}{n})e^{-\frac{y}{n}}} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(1+\frac{x+y}{n})}{(1+\frac{x}{n})(1+\frac{y}{n})} \ \ (*) \ .$$

My question : How do you justify $(*)$, i.e. how do you collect terms of each *infinite* product such a way that you select nth from each, each time?

I have studied theorems in reordering infinite sums but not on infinite products.

Comment: Could you think of the infinite product as an exponential of an infinite sum, and then apply some corollary of the Riemann Rearrangement Theorem?

Comment: @DarrenYao, We have $x,y \in \mathbb{C} \setminus {\{0,-1,-2,...}\}$. So 1. How each term can be written as exp of some complex number? 2. Does Riemann Rearrangement Theorem hold when terms of a series are complex?

Comment: a complex sum converges when both the real and imaginary parts converge. Could you apply Riemann Rearrangement Theorem on the real and imaginary parts separately?

Comment: @DarrenYao, No unfortunately, to be honest I tried your last comment before write it as it came to my mind, but too complicated to see a clear solution